# Picketlink with WildFly 10

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-10, picketlink

I am trying to use PicketLink in my Java EE 7 application. So far the projects compile without errors. But when I try to deploy the application on WildFly 10 it stops with following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picketlink/Identity

First I have tried to add Picketlink (picketlink-impl:2.5.5.SP2) as a dependency to my ear (in lib directory). But this gives quite more exceptions, namely for all internal picketlink classes, one of several exceptions:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/picketlink/internal/AbstractIdentity (Module "..." from Service Module Loader): org/picketlink/Identity

I thought that Picketlink is already deployed in WildFly 10 as a module. Is there any configuration I am missing to activate Picketlink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add picketlink module dependency to your jboss-deployment-structure.xml file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.picketlink"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If you don't have this file it should be placed in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments).

**EDIT:**

It should be placed in the top level deployment. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: I have a EAR with two ejb JARs and a WAR. Where to put it exactly? Every subproject references Picketlink classes.